# How to create map in swig?

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am new to swig. I want to create map of class pointer in Swig. As follow

```
class A;
class B;

namespace std {
%template(MYMap) map<A*, B*>;
}
```

This is not working.

But if I create map like this

```
namespace std {
%template(MYMap) map<int, int>;
}
```

It works.

I think it works for Primitive Built-in Types.
Thank you!

Comment: Why does `Class B;` begin with a capital `C`?

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in comments because I have no way of trying it out, but it's too  hard to type there.  Try typedefs for the pointer types:

```
typedef A *APtr;
typedef B *BPtr;

%template(MyMap) map<APtr, BPtr>;
```

Comment: code is not compiling it is giving some strange error.

Comment: it gives this error 'type_name' : is not a member of 'swig::traits<Type>

Answer (score 0):

Add this line near the top of your .i file:

```
%include "std_map.i"
```

This creates the typemaps for std::map. Also ensure you are using `class B` not `Class B`.